# Browser ignoring page-break

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Even with `!important` the browser seens to be ignoring the page break, see image bellow:

```
@media print {
  section {
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  table {
    page-break-inside: auto;
  }

  thead, td, tr, th {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    page-break-after: auto;
  }
}
```

My html

```
<section>
 
  <table class="table-social">
    <thead>
      <th colspan="3">
        Youtube
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" width="120">
        <img height="120" width="120" src="None">
      </td>
      <td>Usuário</td>
      <td>user</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Link do perfil</td>
      <td><a href="https://youtube.com/user/asdf">https://youtube.com/user/asdf</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table class="table-social">
    <thead>
      <th colspan="3">
        Github
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" width="120">
        <img height="120" width="120" src="None">
      </td>
      <td>Usuário</td>
      <td>user</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Link do perfil</td>
      <td><a href="https://github.com/">https://github.com/</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Could provide some relevant HTML as well? Hopefully [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Pages need to be break at some point. Property value `avoid` try to avoid page break if possible. adding, `page-break-*` has been replaced by `break-*` and browsers may stop supporting this one at any time

Comment: According to caniuse.com the value `avoid` is not supported by Firefox, so you probably shouldn't use it.

Comment: It's Chrome specific, I am using chrome to print to pdf. Not intend to users